# Ionic 2 - Google Api get file list

Tags: cordova, angular, google-drive-api, ionic2

I'm having troubles to retrieve my google's drive file list, since Google loggin will not be available anymore in Hybrid applications I'd to use a plugin to make it through. I followed the ionic documentation auth to log in with my google account (https://docs.ionic.io/services/auth/google-native.html)

I can't paste screenshots, so I'll try to explain my code...

in the app TS (app.module.ts) I've imported CloudSettings and CloudModule from '@ionic/cloud-angular'. Then I'd declared a const called cloudSettings which will be used for the injeccion of CloudModule in the "imports" field in NgModule like this way:

```
imports: [ CloudModule.forRoot(cloudSettings)],
```

Then in my login.ts, I've import and instance, GoogleAuth and User from @ionic/cloud-angular and called this.googleAuth.login() to make login and recieve and object with "token" and "singUp".

After all this work I want to call Google's drive Api, and I tried making and HTTP call to **/drive/v3/reference/files/** and passing throug the header and Authorization: Bearer + token

But it gives me an 401 error saying "Invalid Credentials"

I'm really sad because I've been reading a lot of posts, docs and examples form more than a week.. I don't know what to do.. Any help?